# "E1696: cannot open source file" when I have finished the includedirs in premake5.lua

Tags: c++, visual-studio, premake

When I follow "The Cherno" 's Game Engine series I meet a big problem writing premake5.lua. I thought I had correctly defined the content in includedirs.
like this

```
workspace "Hazel" 
    architecture "x64"
    startproject "Sandbox"

    configurations
    {
        "Debug",
        "Release",
        "Dist"
    }

outputdir="%{cfg.buildcfg}-%{cfg.system}-%{cfg.architecture}"

project "Hazel"
    location "Hazel"
    kind "SharedLib"
    language "C++"
    
    targetdir("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

    files
    {
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.h",
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.cpp"
    }
    
    includedirs
    {
        "$(SolutionDir)Hazel/vendor/spdlog/include"
    }

    filter "system:windows"
        cppdialect "C++17"
        staticruntime "On"
        systemversion "latest"

        defines
        {
            "HZ_PLATFORM_WINDOWS",
            "HZ_BUILD_DLL",
            "_WINDLL"
        }

        postbuildcommands
        {
            ("{COPY} %{cfg.buildtarget.relpath} \"../bin/" .. outputdir .. "/Sandbox/\"")
        }

    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines "HZ_DEBUG"
        symbols "On"

    filter "configurations:Release"
        defines "HZ_RELEASE"
        optimize "On"

    filter "configurations:Dist"
        defines "HZ_DIST"
        optimize "On"

project "Sandbox"
    location "Sandbox"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    language "C++"

    targetdir("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

    files
    {
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.h",
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.cpp"
    }

    includedirs
    {
        "$(SolutionDir)Hazel/vendor/spdlog/include",
        "$(SolutionDir)Hazel/src"
    }

    links
    {
        "Hazel"
    }

    filter "system:windows"
        cppdialect "C++17"
        staticruntime "On"
        systemversion "latest"

        defines
        {
            "HZ_PLATFORM_WINDOWS",
        }

    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines "HZ_DEBUG"
        symbols "On"

    filter "configurations:Release"
        defines "HZ_RELEASE"
        optimize "On"

    filter "configurations:Dist"
        defines "HZ_DIST"
        optimize "On"
```

There is indeed the correct location of spdlog in the additional included directory of the project,
like this:

[image]

But visual studio 2019 still reports error E1696.

I have no idea if it is the problem of the version of premake5(premake-5.0.0-beta1-windows).I hope someone give me some advice.

Comment: Can you check that the directory is correct/what you expect? (it should be visible with button "Macros >>") Note that you provide `location` for project, but not for workspace(solution). So `$(ProjectDir)` != `$(SolutionDir)`